# SWT on OS X: how to handle reopen events

Tags: java, macos, swt

Usually, on OS X when a user clicks the dock icon of a running application, it will show a window - either brings an existing one to front, de-iconifies an existing one or creates a new one.

How to provide a call-back which is invoked when clicking the dock icon of an SWT application?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [SWT: how to handle application events correctly on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6665933/796559)

Also, if you just want to see when a window (or `Shell` in SWT) is shown, then attach an `SWT.Activation` listener...

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't find the answer for the reopen event in my linked question. Hence I asked this new question.