# Using preferences MenuItem SWT

Tags: java, macos, swt, menuitem, preferences

I'm trying to give functionality to the "Preferences.." MenuItem (in the Mac default System menu) for my app but for some reason the on click is not working and I can't see what I'm doing wrong. This is how I get the preferences menuitem:

```
protected MenuItem getPreferencesMenuItem() {
    Menu guiMenu = Display.getDefault().getSystemMenu();
    MenuItem preferencesMenuItem = null;

    if (guiMenu != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < guiMenu.getItemCount(); i++) {
            MenuItem currentMenuItem = guiMenu.getItem(i);
            if (currentMenuItem.getText().contains("Preferences")) {
                preferencesMenuItem = currentMenuItem;
                break;
            } // end if
        } // end for
    } // end if

    return preferencesMenuItem;
}
```

and this is how I'm adding the listener. Is there something I'm missing?

```
MenuItem preferencesMenuItem = this.getPreferencesMenuItem();
if (preferencesMenuItem != null) {
    System.out.println(preferencesMenuItem.getText());
    preferencesMenuItem.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        public void selectedWidget(SelectionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Preferences selected.");
            PreferencesDialog preferencesDialog = new PreferencesDialog(shell_, processPanel_.getImageManager());
            preferencesDialog.open();
            }});
}
```

Comment: You have to interface to some Mac code to do this, see [this blog](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/07/19/configuring-the-os-x-application-menu-for-swt-apps/) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665933/swt-how-to-handle-application-events-correctly-on-os-x)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to open preference dialog.

here is sample code to open Preference dialog with selected preference page id. you should be looking at how to use `ParameterizedCommand` . Hope this helps.

```
public static boolean openPreferencePage(String preferencePageId) {

    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(preferencePageId))
      return false;
    IServiceLocator serviceLocator = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();

    ICommandService commandService = (ICommandService) serviceLocator.getService(ICommandService.class);

    IHandlerService handlerService = (IHandlerService) serviceLocator.getService(IHandlerService.class);

    Command command = commandService.getCommand(IWorkbenchCommandConstants.WINDOW_PREFERENCES);
    IParameter parmDef = null;
    try {
      parmDef = command.getParameter(IWorkbenchCommandConstants.WINDOW_PREFERENCES_PARM_PAGEID);
    } catch (NotDefinedException e) {
      Logger.log(e);
      return false;
    }
    if (parmDef != null) {
      Parameterization[] params = new Parameterization[] { new Parameterization(parmDef, preferencePageId) };

      ParameterizedCommand paramCommand = new ParameterizedCommand(command, params);
      try {
        handlerService.executeCommand(paramCommand, null);
        return true;
      } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.log(e);
        return false;
      }
    }
    return false;

  }
```